# How can I do bulk indexing in AWS Elastic Search

Tags: laravel, elasticsearch

I have a database of 200,000 records - In AWS Elastic Search, we want to index these documents, however, indexing them one at (using a laravel console command) a time is taking very long.

How can we do a bulk index to speed things up.

Here is our current indexing function

```
public function handle()
{
    $this->init();
    $pageSize=10;
    $indexName = env('AWS_VIDEO_INDEX');
    $videos = Video::orderBy('id','desc')->chunk($pageSize, function ($vserverVideos) use ($indexName){
        foreach($vserverVideos as $video){
            /**
             * @var $video Video
             * var/class[]
             */
            $subtitles = $video->getSubtitles();
            $params = [
                'index' => $indexName,
                'id'=>$video->id,
                'body'  => [
                    'id'=>$video->id,
                    'title'=>$video->title,
                    'description'=>$video->description,
                    'jobStatus'=>$video->jobStatus,
                    'youtubeId'=>$video->youtubeId,
                    'thumbnail'=>$video->thumbnail,
                    'playlistId'=>$video->playlistId,
                    'category'=>$video->category,
                    'channelId'=>$video->channelId,
                    'publishedDate'=>$video->publishedDate,
                    'created_at'=>$video->created_at->toIso8601String(),
                    'updated_at'=>$video->updated_at->toIso8601String(),
                    'url'=>$video->url,
                    'subtitles'=>$subtitles,
                ]
            ];
            $response = $this->elasticClient->index($params);
            if ($response['result']==='updated'||$response['result']==='created'){
                $result = $response['result'];
                $numSubs = count($subtitles);
                $this->line("Indexed ($result) $video->title with $numSubs subtitles");
            }
        }
    });



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am not familiar with laravel. But, the elasticsearch suggested way is through logstash or you can also have a look at the bulk index API https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html. Elastic used to have rivers for keeping data in sync from db previously, but it has now been discontinued in favour of logstash itself. What is the database here? Lombok now supports input plugin for most of the popular databases now.

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with Laravel again, but here's a way in `python`, using the **elasticsearch** package, that you can achieve a "bulk indexing" :

```
import psycopg2
conn = psycopg2.connect(host="<host>",database='<database>',user='<user>',password='<password>')
cur = conn.cursor()
# just fetching records from say, a postgres table
cur.execute("select * from public.music")
res = cur.fetchall()

marr = []
for r in res:
    mobj = {
        '_id': int(r[0]), 'routing': r[4],
        'created_at': r[1].strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), 'updated_at': r[2].strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
        'sound_id': r[3], 'music_id': r[4], 'music_name': r[5], 'music_author': r[6], 'music_original': r[7],
        'play_url': r[8], 'cover_thumb': r[9], 'cover_medium': r[10], 'fetched_times': r[11], 'cover_large': r[12]
    }
    marr.append(mobj)
```

and then :

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch, helpers
import json 

client = Elasticsearch('http://<es-ip>:9200/') # replace with AWS ES domain accordingly
resp = helpers.bulk(client, uarr, index="music")
```

resp = helpers.bulk(client, marr, index="tk-music")